# Using git with React Native team

Tags: git, react-native

My current `.gitignore` file has:

```
# OSX
# .DS_Store

# Xcode
# build/
*.pbxuser !default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3 !default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3 !default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3 !default.perspectivev3 xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate project.xcworkspace

# Android/IntelliJ
# build/ .idea .gradle local.properties
*.iml

# node.js
node_modules/ npm-debug.log yarn-error.log

# BUCK buck-out/ \.buckd/
*.keystore

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/

*/fastlane/report.xml
*/fastlane/Preview.html
*/fastlane/screenshots

# Bundle artifact
*.jsbundle

#React Files
android/
ios/
```

Then, I did the usual.

```
git add .
git commit -am "First commit"
git push -u origin master
```

It got loaded up.

When the team member did `git clone`
and then did `npm install`

It did not load anything!

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gmxWorldWide",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

It does not install anything.

I come from `php` background where `composer.json` would be replicated across the team and `composer install` would do the trick.

How is it different and what can be done to enable `npm install` do the work?

EDIT:

The code was create using `react-native init` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out React comes with a built-in command.

We performed:

`react-native eject`

and it re-created the Android and iOS folders with native code back in the project.

After pull:

```
npm install
react-native eject
```

Answer (score 1):

Your required modules are already loaded when you clone the app since you have committed the `node_modules` directory to git.You have to ignore `node_modules` from the repository.But i see in your `.gitignore` it has been commented

```
# node.js
# node_modules/ npm-debug.log yarn-error.log
```

Update that to following(un-comment)

```
# node.js
node_modules/ npm-debug.log yarn-error.log
```

best way to create react native app is by  using `create-react-native-app`. Read more here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

EDIT:
You have to commit the `package-lock.json` file to make sure all your team in same set of library versions.But anyway this might add bit of a hassle sine each `npm install` might update the existing packages to their desired version as mentioned in the `package.json` file.

more details on package-lock.json here : https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

SECOND EDIT: 
If you want to lock the versions then use package.json file to do it.Just use exact package version instead of using version ranges(<=,~,^)

Fixed versions on package.json

```
....
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "watchman": "1.0.0"
  },
....
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. The question is to make use of git and npm install to replicate that team is on the same page.

Comment: The modules are created dynamically by react-native. I have answered my question. See below.